# dompdf - Create pdf file once, but make it imposible to reopen it later?

Tags: dompdf

I am using dompdf to create pdf files. But whant I want to be done is to create once the file, so the user can see the contents, but protect the file so the user once he close it, he can't reopen it later. Is that possible OR should I use other program?

Answer (score 3):

This really isn't possible. It sounds like what you want is for the document to be destroyed after first reading (Mission Impossible style). That's not how the web works. A file that can be accessed over the web can be easily downloaded and opened offline.

Certainly there are hacks around this, but they would be fairly involved to implement. I once created a Flash-based viewer that loaded another file that contained the actual document. Any tech-savvy user could still obtain the original document by examining the network traffic, but your average non-technical user wouldn't know how to do it.

You do have options for enabling restrictions in a PDF, but the user will always be able to save it and re-open it later. Probably what you want to do is implement restrictions on the document and [load it in an iframe](http://www.ahfb2000.com/webmaster_help_desk/showpost.php?s=fe92c1665e42feb127a847f54ca53d1a&p=38431&postcount=6) to prevent saving.

You can implement print/copy restrictions as follows:

```
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->get_canvas()->get_cpdf()->setEncryption('', 'ownerpass', array());
$dompdf->stream();
```

The parameters of setEncryption are:

1. string, user password (restrictions apply)
2. string, owner password (unlocks document)
3. array, strings indicating allowed actions when user password is supplied (e.g. print, copy). If left blank the user is limited to saving the document.

Comment: Thank you a lot for you comments. I will try later like you say. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

A pdf is a document, it has no scripting instructions, maybe you want to embed it in an exe, have the exe extract it, and keep checking the lock bit, as soon as it is clear delete it.

Comment: I am using a web page generating the PDF with dompdf. I am not sure how to create an exe....